# nth-child selector not applied when dynamically inserting two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a `div` dynamically as an HTML string and append it to a container.

```js
$('#add-row').click(function(){
  var row="<div class='red'></div>";
  $('#container').append(row);
});
```

```css
div.red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
div.red:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button type='button' id="add-row">Add</button>
```

This much works well. I need now to create two `div`s and append them to a container.

```js
$('#add-row').click(function(){
  var row="<div class='red'></div><div class='not-red'></div>";
  $('#container').append(row);
});
```

```css
div.red,div.not-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
div.red:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button type='button' id="add-row">Add</button>
```

The problem arises after appending the `div`'s; specifically, `div.red:nth-child(even)` is no longer applied. [From what I've understood](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), this shouldn't be a problem with the correct selector. This might be a situation where `:nth-of-type` fits better, but my attempts haven't yielded success.

Comment: the nth-child(even) are all not-red in your case ....

Comment: @Temani Afif, how so?

Comment: nth-child(even) with get the *even* child elements ... and all these element are not-red .. so your selector will select nothing ... replace with *odd* and see --> this is because nth-child don't consider classes like you thing

Comment: @Temani Afif how does that work with the `div.red` selector?

Comment: It is `div.red:nth-child(odd)`.

Comment: it doesn't work with div.red :) ... nth-child don't consider any class or element ... read it like this "Give me the nth-child I need, then let me see if they have the selector I want" --> or all your element that are *even* doesn't have .red class

Comment: read the duplicate question and you will get a more detailed explanation